# How do I set the authorisation header to a bearer token generated for other API requests

Tags: angular, typescript, proxy

I have created a service that calls to a third party endpoint.
I have used their auth endpoint to generate a bearer token which I need to use with other api calls.

Since this is a 3rd party API I'm calling to my target urls and headers are built on a proxy.

Now that I have generated the access_token how can I add this string to the authorisation header?

[image]

**Component**

```
 showOAuth() {
    this.zebraService.getOAuth()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('Zebra Response: ', data);
      console.log(data.body);
      this.OAuth = data.body;

      this.access_token = this.OAuth.access_token;
      console.log(this.access_token);
      });
  }
```

**Proxy**

```
"/zebraAccessApi": {
  "target": "https://api.com",
  "secure": true,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/zebraAccessApi": ""
  },
  "headers": {
    "client_id": "",
    "client_secret": ""
  }
},

"/zebraSetAppLed": {
  "target": "https://api.com/setAppLed",
  "secure": true,
  "changeOrigin": true,
  "pathRewrite": {
    "^/zebraSetAppLed": ""
  },
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": ""
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
zebraOAuthUrl = '/zebraAccessApi';
    zebraSetAppLedUrl = '/zebraSetAppLed';

    public getOAuth() {    
        let options = {
            observe: 'response' as 'body',
            response: 'json'
        };
        return this.http.get(this.zebraOAuthUrl, options);
    }
```

Comment: Angular provides a great way to intercept every api request using HttpInterceptor, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 3):

You could write an interceptor to add the necessary headers:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const token = <YOUR_TOKEN>;

  // if no token add some default stuff or just return the req
  const reqNoToken = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    }
  });
  if (!token) {
    return next.handle(reqNoToken);
  }
  // this is basically where the magic happens
  const req = request.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  });
  return next.handle(req).pipe(
    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  );
}
```

An interceptor does what its name suggests, it intercepts your request and in the above case adds the necessary token and headers, or it doesn't if no token is set.

I think you have to alter the function to your needs, but I guess this should be no problem.

Also please read about angular interceptors here, as I don't want to go into full detail about the concept: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: Thanks @chriszichrisz I'll read up on it and see if I can get it to work for me.

Comment: How would the interceptor be setup to be only used by some API calls and not all API calls?

Comment: afaik this is not possible, and in my understanding using interceptors only for some calls is not how it was designed. If you have only one call, you might set the headers directly on the .get(url: string, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders } ...  OR you create a condition in the interceptor that executes based on the request.url and returns all others. I really suggest you read the angular documentation, because how to change the headers on a single request is really angular 101 and it is pretty well documented, not only in the offical doc, but also in many other tutorials.